# Match records on different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-view

I have to match a table of **Agents** to a table **Clients** based on a varying number of matching columns, some match on all columns, others only match on one, or two or three; and not the same columns. Examples:

**Clients** table has columns

`ClientID, System, Country, Office`

Example data:

```
01   ABC   US   CT
02   ABC   US   RI
03   ABC   US   MA
04   DEF   US   AZ
04   GHI   CA   PQ
05   ABC   ZZ   ZZ
```

**Agents** table has columns

`AgentID, System, Country, Office`

Example data:

```
A1   ABC   US   CT
A2   ABC        RI
A3   ABC   US   MA
B1   DEF   US   
B2   GHI
```

Problem: All **Agents** have a **System** value, but some **Agents** have no values for **Country** or **Office**, some have only **System**, some have **System** and **Country**, some have **System** and **Office**, and the rest have all 3: **System**, **Country** and **Office**. If a **Client** only matches 1 or 2 fields to an **Agent**, they're treated like "wildcards" and are considered a match for the appropriate **Agent**.

How can I create a View that matches every Client and Agent? And shows any Clients that have *no* corresponding Agent, such as Client 05 above?

So far all I've been able to come up with is to create some kind of table and append the records in 3 or 4 steps, but that is so messy and clumsy, and adds another table to the mix.

I tried a **COALESCE** statement, and joining with a **LIKE** statement and surrounding fields with **%**, but nothing I've tried gives valid results.

Would this call for a Temp table or a **CTE**? Or something? I'm stuck!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the best match, with `NULL` values acting as wildcards.  If so, then `apply` is the way to go:

```
select a.*, a.agentid
from clients c outer apply
     (select top (1) a.*
      from agents a
      where (a.System = c.system or a.System is null) and
            (a.Country = c.Country or a.Country is null) and
            (a.Office = c.Office or a.Office is null)
      order by (case when a.system = c.system then 1 else 0 end) +
               (case when a.Country = c.Country then 1 else 0 end) +
               (case when a.Office = c.Office then 1 else 0 end) desc
     ) a;
```

Comment: Good idea, Gordon, I'll try that and see if it works. (Frankly I think the folks at work who are providing this data have a mess on their hands, and I have no idea how they came up with this, it seems hacky!)

Comment: @BrianBattles . . . This sort of "defaulting values" type of data is not that unusual.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want:

```
create view v_clients_agents as
select c.*, a.agentID
from clients c
left join agents a 
    on a.system = c.system
    and (a.country is null or a.country = c.country)
    and (a.office  is null or a.office  = c.office)
```

This attempts to join both tables on `system`, `country` and `office`, while allowing `null` values in `agents(country, office)`. When the join did not find a match, column `agentID` is `null` in the resultset.

Note that, depending on your data, this technique might lead to duplicate `clients` rows in the resultset.

Comment: The problem with this is that if Agent A2 is supposed to be linked to all Clients in System ABC and Office RI no matter what their Country, and Agent B3 is supposed to be linked to all Clients in System DEF with no Office but Country US.... They data isn't consistent.

The only thing that would make sense to me is to have all possible valid permutations of the Client values in the Agents table, but they don't want to create and maintain all those hundreds of extra entries here.